# Как убрать подписку в подписке c помощью rxjs angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub.add(
      this.orderService.getOrders().pipe(
        map((orders: CreatedOrders[]) => {
          return orders.map((order: CreatedOrders) => {
            const price = [];
            order.productItems.map((item: CartItem) => {
              this.orderService.getCreatedCartItems(item).pipe(
                map((itemData: ItemContent) => {
                  this.orderService.productPrice = Number((itemData.priceDto.price * item.quantity).toFixed(CONSTANTS.two));
                  price.push(this.orderService.productPrice);
                  if (price.length === order.productItems.length) {
                    this.orderService.methodSum(price)
                  }
                  return orders
                })
              ).pipe(
                mergeMap(orders => {
                  this.newOrdersData.next([])
                  for (let i = CONSTANTS.zero; i < orders.length; i++) {
                    this.newOrder = { ...orders[i], price: this.orderService.orderPrice[i] }
                    this.newOrdersData.next([...this.newOrdersData.value, this.newOrder]);
                  }
                  return this.newOrdersData
                })
              ).subscribe()
            })
          })
        }),
      ).subscribe()
    )
  }
```

Подскажите, как избавится от внутренней подписки (subscribe) с помощью rxjs?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317494/is-it-good-to-call-subscribe-inside-subscribe you should use mergeMap or try to use tap & swichMap